# Publish/Subscribe not working automatically when data added to the mongodb

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I have the following publisher and subscriber code.

It works for the first time when the app starts, but when I try to insert data directly into the Mongo database, it will not automatically update the user screen or I don't see the alert popping.

Am I missing something?

### Publish

```
Meteor.publish('userConnections', function(){
    if(!this.userId){
       return;
    }
    return Connections.find({userId: this.userId});
})
```

### Subscribe

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('userConnections').then(function () {
    var userContacts = $scope.$meteorCollection(Connections);
     alert("subscriber userConnections is called");
    if (userContacts && userContacts[0]) {
         ....
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you are not using angular-meteor 1.3 you should be. The API has changed **a lot**. $meteorSubscribe has been deprecated!

To directly answer your question, $meteorSubscribe is a promise that gets resolved (*only once*) when the subscription is ready. So, it will only ever be called once. If you look at the [documentation for subscribe](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/subscribe) you'll see how to make the binding "reactive", by assigning it to a scope variable. In your case it would be something like:

```
$scope.userContacts = $scope.$meteorCollection(Connections);
```

Doing it this way, when the collection gets updated, the $scope.userContacts should get updated as well.